# Trying to get pagedown bootstrap to work on meteor text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, pagedown

I often have this problem with jquery and meteor, I get a undefined is not a function, and I just cant figure out why.

Here is my code for [pagedown-bootstrap](http://kevo.io/pagedown-bootstrap/) package i installed. WRONG LINK [this](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown) is the right source

```
Template.postSubmit.rendered = function () {



$("textarea#pagedownMe").pagedownBootstrap();

};
```

My html template

```
<template name="postSubmit">
  <form class="submitForm">

      <label for="date">Date</label>
      <input name="date" type="text" value="" placeholder="Date"/>


      <label for ="title">Title</label>
      <input name ="title" type="text" value="" placeholder="title"/>

      <label for="content">Content</label>
    <textarea id="pagedownMe" name="content"  class="form-control" rows="10">
This is the *first* editor.
------------------------------

Just plain **Markdown**, except that the input is sanitized:

<marquee>I'm the ghost from the past!</marquee>
</textarea>



      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</template>
```

The error I am getting

```
Exception from Deps afterFlush function function: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.Template.postSubmit.rendered (http://localhost:3000/client/postsPagedown.js?05d5727bffc4120f5b1e1765e9451a7571bbd788:5:26)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ui.js?f0696b7e9407b8f11e5838e7e7820e9b6d7fc92f:426:23
    at _assign.flush (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?91f1235baecd83915f7d3a7328526dbba41482be:345:13)
```

**Pacakges from atmosphere**

main package [pagedown-bootstrap](https://atmospherejs.com/package/pagedown-bootstrap)  dependant [marked](https://atmospherejs.com/package/marked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong code, I looked at the wrong resource.

**JS**

```
$(function () {
     var converter = new Markdown.Converter();
     var editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter);
     editor.run();
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wmd-panel">
     <div id="wmd-button-bar">
     </div>
     <textarea class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input">
This is the *first* editor.
------------------------------

Just plain **Markdown**, except that the input is sanitized:

<marquee>I'm the ghost from the past!</marquee>
     </textarea>
</div>
<div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to convert the package to work with meteor. The main thing to do is un-variable scope the main variables.

You need to look for files which have variables that are accessed by other variables. Here are two questions that go over the basics of [what meteor does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791621/how-is-package-scope-achieved) and [how to get passed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788366/defining-variable-in-meteor-js)

I would suggest you make it a Meteor package that contains the pagedown package with the variables modified to be global. This way you can namespace the project away from your app and still have it work.

This is a good tutorial on how to make a package: http://www.vintyge.com/blog/2012/12/creating-a-basic-meteorite-smart-package

Sorry about all the links but looking at the package's source it wont be as simple as just copying and pasting it in.

---

#### Shortcut but slightly weird way.

You can place the packages files in `/client/compatibility`. Though you may have to rename the files so they load in the correct order. Meteor loads files alphabetically, so you would have to rename the first file `a.js` (Markdown.Converter.js - I think) and the next `b.js`

Comment: it was available in atmosphere when i installed mrt add pagedown-bootstrap isnt it already a package.

Comment: @AndersKitson I can't really tell at the moment, atmosphere's been down for the past few hours for me, but if you did that it sounds right. Just check you've also added it as a meteor package with `meteor list --using` (is it in the list?)

Comment: Yeah atmosphere has been pretty slow but this is the link https://atmospherejs.com/package/pagedown-bootstrap there is no real documentation. and it shows up on the list.

Comment: @Akshat Im still having trouble with this and I am using the pagedown-bootstrap package from atomsphere.